# Expanding on Hello World tutorial

Tags: java, android, xml

I am writing my first app ever and am still learning `Java` and `XML`. The android tutorial sets two activities, one that receives user input and another activity that simply gets the input and displays on another screen. The second activity looks something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the message from Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

My question is this: how can I use 'message' in xml instead of this java document? I would like to avoid using setContentView(textView) because I would like to add more to the activity screen. What solutions do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

`setContentView()` is required in order to load the UI for your Activity. You have two options to create the main View which you send to `setContentView()`:

1. You can create the layout with Java code.
2. You can create the layout in a XML file.

Usually the second is preferred for a static UI and the first is used when the UI is more dynamic.

I suggest that you familiarize yourself with [the Official Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html). In particular, you should look at [UI Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html) for understanding the Android UI framework.

You might also be interested in using a [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) to store the keys used for the "extras" which are stored in the `Intent` which is sent to your `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand but if I do, put your `TextView` inside a `layout` in an xml file and use that in `setContentView)`. Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your message"/>  // it is better to use strings.xml instead of hard-coded strings
</LinearLayout>
```

Say this is called `myLayout.xml`

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{
TextView tv1;
rotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
}
```

You can't add to the xml file at runtime but you could now set your text in this `TextView` to whatever you want

```
  public class MyClass extends Activity{
TextView tv1;
rotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setText("Other Text");
}
```

I hope this answered your question as I'm a little confused on exactly what your question is